# Wrapping long text of multibutton

Tags: codenameone

I implemented drop down list with MultiButton, but if I have long text I want the text to wrap itself (i.e. it need to display one below the other after reaching the end), but now its in single line, at the end of dialog/ container I can't see the remaining text. How do I implement this?

I implemented using Span button, but the there is large space between two items which looks awful.

So, any suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: Do you have any code?  What have you tried?  See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

`MultiButton` doesn't wrap. `SpanButton` supports wrapping so you can use that. Alternatively you can create a customized lead component.